# Unable to display correct data using date in crystal report

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, crystal-reports

I have write code to display data using crystal reports. I have set parameter fields but it seems like it's not functioning well. Here is an example:

**Database**

```
   1/12/2012        A
   5/12/2012        B
   9/12/2012        C
   13/12/2012       D
```

Conditions used to display report:
Start date = 1/12/2012
End date   = 15/12/2012

Here it just displays data for `13/12/2012 - D` but with

Start date = 1/12/2012
End date   = 9/12/2012

it displays all the data:

```
   1/12/2012-A
   5/12/2012-B
   9/12/2012-C
   13/12/2012-D
```

Here is my vb.net code:

```
    Dim reader As OleDbDataReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader
    If reader.Read = True Then
        cryRpt = New ReportDocument()
        cryRpt.Load("C:\Users\user\Documents\LabSystem\LabSystem\Report\Spec.rpt")

        crParameterDiscreteValue.Value = txtDateFrom.Text
        crParameterFieldDefinitions = cryRpt.DataDefinition.ParameterFields
        crParameterFieldDefinition = crParameterFieldDefinitions("fromDate")
        crParameterValues = crParameterFieldDefinition.CurrentValues

        crParameterValues.Clear()
        crParameterValues.Add(crParameterDiscreteValue)
        crParameterFieldDefinition.ApplyCurrentValues(crParameterValues)

        crParameterDiscreteValue.Value = txtDateTo.Text
        crParameterFieldDefinitions = cryRpt.DataDefinition.ParameterFields
        crParameterFieldDefinition = crParameterFieldDefinitions("toDate")
        crParameterValues = crParameterFieldDefinition.CurrentValues

        crParameterValues.Add(crParameterDiscreteValue)
        crParameterFieldDefinition.ApplyCurrentValues(crParameterValues)

        CrTables = cryRpt.Database.Tables
        Dim crTable As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table
        For Each crTable In CrTables

            crtableLogoninfo = crTable.LogOnInfo
        Next
        crtableLogoninfo.ConnectionInfo = crConnectionInfo
        crTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(crtableLogoninfo)


        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryRpt
        CrystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport()

    Else
        MsgBox("No records exists")
    End If
    reader.Close()
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox("Error in select query: " + ex.Message)
End Try
```

Here's the condition in crystal report:

```
{1BK.edate}=({?toDate} TO {?fromDate})
```

Comment: what is the datatype of eDate?

Comment: I use Date/Time. using ms access

Comment: when you run the report in CR does it work correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd try in this order:

1. Change selection criteria to `{1BK.edate} = ({?fromDate} to
   {?toDate})`
2. Change selection criteria to `{1BK.edate} >= {?fromDate}
   and {1BK.edate} <= {?toDate}`
3. Change selection criteria to
   `{1BK.edate} >= '#' + {?fromDate} + '#' and {1BK.edate} <= '#' +
   {?toDate} + '#'` (make sure your parameters are strings in this
   instance

Answer (score 0):

it works when a change parameter field in crystal report to

> Date

then the condition is

`{1BK.edate} = ({?fromDate} to {?toDate})`